# Error 301 / 404 uploading data with appcfg.py App Engine 1.8 for python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

7.5 to 1.8 in App Engine SDK and now I can't do upload data. 
This is the error:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --url=http://192.168.1.106:8001/ --filename=database --num_threads=4 --rps_limit=500
08:46 PM Uploading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20130528.204655
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 500/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
Error 301: --- begin server output ---

--- end server output ---
```

When I use: /_ah/remote_api this is the error.

```
appcfg.py upload_data --url=http://192.168.1.106:8001/_ah/remote_api --filename=database --num_threads=4 --rps_limit=500
08:48 PM Uploading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20130528.204813
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 500/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
Error 404: --- begin server output ---
404 Not Found
The resource could not be found.

--- end server output ---
```

I've test it with ***localhost*** (using the default configuration) and the result is exactly the same. 
Why 1.8 version is not working when exactly the same is working OK with 1.7.5? 
Any ideas?

**EDIT:
I've test with bulkloader too to make the thing easier, this is the result:**

1) I've dump the database in my APP in GAE with this command:

```
bulkloader.py --dump --url=<myapp> --filename=dumpBetaServer
```

and everything is ok. I have like result a dump called dumpBetaServer.

2) Now, I try to restore this dump to my Development Server:

```
bulkloader.py --restore --url=http://192.168.1.106:8001 --filename=dumpBetaServer --num_threads=1
```

And this is the result:

```
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20130529.081227
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/bulkloader.py", line 171, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/bulkloader.py", line 167, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 4401, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 4397, in main
    return _PerformBulkload(arg_dict)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 4165, in _PerformBulkload
    throttle_class=throttle_class)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 4072, in _GetRemoteAppId
    rpc_server_factory=throttled_rpc_server_factory, secure=secure)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 659, in GetRemoteAppId
    app_id = GetRemoteAppIdFromServer(server, path, rtok)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 568, in GetRemoteAppIdFromServer
    response = server.Send(path, payload=None, **urlargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 393, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 301: Moved Permanently
```

When I try with this other command:

```
bulkloader.py --restore --url=http://192.168.1.106:8001/_ah/remote_api --filename=dumpBetaServer --num_threads=1
```

This is the result:

```
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20130529.081755
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/bulkloader.py", line 171, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/bulkloader.py", line 167, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 4401, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 4397, in main
    return _PerformBulkload(arg_dict)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 4165, in _PerformBulkload
    throttle_class=throttle_class)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 4072, in _GetRemoteAppId
    rpc_server_factory=throttled_rpc_server_factory, secure=secure)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 659, in GetRemoteAppId
    app_id = GetRemoteAppIdFromServer(server, path, rtok)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 568, in GetRemoteAppIdFromServer
    response = server.Send(path, payload=None, **urlargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 393, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

**EDIT 2:** 
This is my app.yaml

```
#  For Google App Engine deployment, copy this file to app.yaml
#  and edit as required
#  See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html
#  and http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/11?search=app.yaml

application: <myapp>
version: 31
api_version: 1

# use this line for Python 2.5
#
runtime: python

# use these lines for Python 2.7
# upload app with: appcfg.py update web2py (where 'web2py' is web2py's root directory)
#
# runtime: python27
# threadsafe: true    # true for WSGI & concurrent requests (Python 2.7 only)

default_expiration: "24h"   # for static files

handlers:

- url: /(?P<a>.+?)/static/(?P<b>.+)
  static_files: applications/\1/static/\2
  upload: applications/(.+?)/static/(.+)
  secure: always

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: applications/welcome/static/favicon.ico
  upload: applications/welcome/static/favicon.ico

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: applications/welcome/static/robots.txt
  upload: applications/welcome/static/robots.txt

- url: .*
  script: gaehandler.py         # CGI
#  script: gaehandler.wsgiapp    # WSGI (Python 2.7 only)
  secure: optional

admin_console:
  pages:
  - name: Appstats
    url: /_ah/stats


builtins:
- remote_api: on
- appstats: on
- admin_redirect: on
- deferred: on
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you show the options you are passing to the devappserver command?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, the options are: --admin_host=192.168.1.106, no more options.

Comment: I've added more info: the same, but this time using bulkloader. This time I've the same result but more "verbose".... I hope this can help, I'm really desperate with this problem.

Comment: Do you have the remote api builtin enabled in your development app. Also is http://192.168.1.106:8001 the url of your app? The devappserver reports this witha a message like: Starting server "default" running at: http://localhost:8080.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, Thank you for stick with my problem!. This is the message:.
INFO     2013-05-30 06:20:58,314 api_server.py:153] Starting API server at: http://localhost:53642
INFO     2013-05-30 06:20:58,323 dispatcher.py:164] Starting server "default" running at: http://localhost:9080
INFO     2013-05-30 06:20:58,337 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://192.168.1.106:8001

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I've added app.yaml.

Comment: Ok, so you would need to connect to the default server (your app), not the admin server (you can see the admin server as the equivalent of the admin console running on appengine.google.com).

Comment: Wow!!... yes!!.... Finally it works, thank you for the tip!. I've remove the option --admin_host==192.168.1.106, and I've use this command: bulkloader.py --restore --url=http://localhost:9080/_ah/remote_api --filename=dumpBetaServer --num_threads=4 . You've to enter a correct User/Pwd and now it works!. Thank you Sebastian, how can I accept your answer?.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I added a response summarizing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new devappserver starts different services at different ports. In the general case it will start three services: your app (default server), admin server (equivalent to the admin console at appengine.google.com) and an API server. The logs will show something like:

> INFO     2013-05-31 16:34:58,397 api_server.py:148] Starting API
> server at: `http://localhost:48392`
>
> INFO     2013-05-31 16:34:58,408 dispatcher.py:96] Starting server "default" running at:
> `http://localhost:8080`
>
> INFO     2013-05-31 16:34:58,420 admin_server.py:112] Starting admin server at:
> `http://localhost:8000`

The url you need to pass to the bulkuploader is the one of your app (default server).